How to populate a Caffeine AsyncCache with Scaffeine and return a Map without a race condition?
I'm using Scaffeine (a Scala wrapper around Caffeine) to try and populate an AsyncCache using async loader functions, then I want to wait until the cache is populated, and return a Map (synchronous).
Unfortunately, I'm running into a race condition, so I think I may be making some bad assumptions. See comments in the code below.
import com.github.blemale.scaffeine.{AsyncCache, Scaffeine}

import scala.collection.concurrent
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

sealed trait Cacheable[A] {
  def cacheKey(obj: A): Any
  def bytes(obj: A): Future[Array[Byte]]
}

object CacheRaceDebug {

  def buildCache[A](objs: Seq[A])(implicit cacheable: Cacheable[A]): Future[concurrent.Map[Any, Array[Byte]]] = {
    val cache: AsyncCache[Any, Array[Byte]] = Scaffeine().buildAsync()
    Future
      .sequence(objs.map { o =>
        val key: Any = implicitly[Cacheable[A]].cacheKey(o)
        val bytes: Future[Array[Byte]] = implicitly[Cacheable[A]].bytes(o)
        // bytes is an async "computation" for something like a generated image or download.
        // This is intended to populate the cache.
        // We'll wait for the returned `Future` from this an all other loads to know when the cache should be populated.
        cache.getFuture(key, _ => bytes)
      })
      .map((allBytes: Seq[Array[Byte]]) => {
        // Now that all the `Future`s returned from `getFuture` above have resolved,
        // we (APPARENTLY INCORRECTLY) assume the cache has been loaded and all values are ready.
        // The intention here is to return a map that can used synchronously with all values.
        cache.synchronous.asMap
      })
  }

}

I suspect this is not related to Scala or Scaffeine specifically, but that I'm making an incorrect assumption about Caffeine's getFuture method. Is the problem that the Future returned by this doesn't guarantee that the resolved value is actually in the cache already?
Is there a better way to wait for the all loads in progress to complete and for the cache to be updated before calling cache.synchronous.toMap?
Workaround
...or should I just build the synchronous Map manually in Scala and forget about trying to get the map from the cache directly, or at all?
Something like this works fine (returning a tuple with k->v, then using _.toMap to build one from the entries), but it's still helpful to know where my assumptions are wrong around Scaffeine or Caffeine for future reference:
Future
  .traverse(objs) { obj =>
    cache.getFuture(key, _ => obj.bytes)
      .map(bytes => key -> bytes)
  }.map(_.toMap)

and in this specific scenario where all the objects are known locally, it's easy to deduplicate they keys first and avoid the cache completely.
Caffeine "directly" also didn't work
I also tried something similar without Scaffeine and that had the same issue:
val cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().asInstanceOf[Caffeine[Any, Array[Byte]]].buildAsync[Any, Array[Byte]]()
Future
  .traverse(objs) { obj =>
    cache
      .get(obj.cacheKey, asJavaBiFunction((_: Any, _: Executor) => obj.bytes.toJava.toCompletableFuture))
      .toScala
  }
  .map(_ => cache.synchronous.asMap.asScala.toMap)


I’m very rusty on scala. The async cache stores a future as the mapping and attaches a dependent action to update its metadata when complete. So once it’s resolved then the value should be visible, though callbacks might be in progress (e.g. remove if failed). The asMap view is the live contents, and synchronous would give the immediate result if the future is done successfully, else null as if absent. I’d have expected getAll is what you’d want as it gives an immutable map for the requested keys.

Sounds like my assumptions align with what you're saying. In the above, I was just assuming that if we were just putting 1 thing in the cache, and the Future returned by cache.getFuture(key, _ => bytes) was resolved, then calling cache.synchronous.asMap should always give me a Map with that 1 key populated. My similar code worked fine 1 at a time, but I was missing an item in my cache ~20-50% of the time with load. getAll is essentially what I want, but I'm using a different loader function for each key, which is why I iterate.

Are you using Scafeinne just to build the map? If so, then yeah I would remove it. Your assumptions feel correct so I wonder if the issue is not just Caffeine removing some values because they are too old or you reached the max number of elements in the cache?

PS: Use Future.traverse(seq)(f) rather than Future.sequence(seq.map(f))

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes I'm just calling .synchronous, which calls underlying.synchronous(). I added a workaround that I started to use, and it fixed the issue, but not knowing why irks me a little. However, since my use case is pretty simple, just avoiding this path does actually work. I could actually avoid Caffeine completely, but using an AsyncCache via Scaffeine seemed like a nice Scala-syntax-friendly way to deduplicate requests on the same key without worrying about locks or race conditions or calling Java's putIfAbsent directly. Also, thanks for the tip!

I mean, just make a Set of the keys before creating the Futures, or use distinct.

Good point. In this example, that definitely works. I hope to use a similar pattern and cache shared in a larger context later, but since this implementation has all the objects present locally, deduplicating the keys first and avoiding the cache is much simpler. I was able to reproduce the problem with Caffeine from Scala "directly" (with Java converters), but I'll just go with the cache-less solution for now and move on.

If you think it’s a bug in caffeine, please submit an issue with a Java reproducer.

BTW, a bit off-topic, but these are the kind of problems with type systems like cats-effect or ZIO excel. For example, you may rather use a MapRef to handle all this.

@BenManes will do. With Java 8, Caffeine 2.9.x, Scala 2.12 and related conversions, there's a lot of variables, so there could be something weird about my setup. I don't have enough confidence there's a bug right now (vs something in my setup), but if we use this pattern more in the future, the clarified expectations are a big help to know what to hunt for.
